# Why does my url return the same page even when i change the query parameters?

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests, screen-scraping

Please help me understand this, 
the url i am trying to work on looks something like this :

```
url = "https://www.sixt.ie/php/reservation/offerselect"
```

The following is the form data after filling info :

```
form_data = "tab_identifier=1526583730&uci=1385&rci=1385&uli=IE&rli=IE&layout=list&posl=IE&is_corpcust=&has_social_login=&pu_eq_ret=1&uda=25.05.2018&uti=10%3A00&geo_del_name=&geo_del_street=&geo_del_postcode=&geo_del_town=&geo_del_country=AT&del_note=&rda=26.05.2018&rti=09%3A30&geo_col_name=&geo_col_street=&geo_col_postcode=&geo_col_town=&geo_col_country=AT&col_note="
```

when I do this:

```
url = url+"?"+form_data

driver.get(url)
```

It wont work, why? 
I am trying to manually change the `uda` and `rda` values in the form_data to get results for other dates.. But that doesn't work too !

I am new to this, any help is appreciated

I am trying to manually change the `uda` and `rda` dates in the link above to get the rates, but the browser loads the same page again.

Why is this happening ? 
How to work around it ?

Thank you so much !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do this manually you get this url in the browser:

```
https://www.sixt.ie/php/reservation?tab_identifier=1526583730&uci=1385&rci=1385&uli=IE&rli=IE&layout=list&posl=IE&is_corpcust=&has_social_login=&pu_eq_ret=1&uda=25.05.2018&uti=10%3A00&geo_del_name=&geo_del_street=&geo_del_postcode=&geo_del_town=&geo_del_country=AT&del_note=&rda=26.05.2018&rti=09%3A30&geo_col_name=&geo_col_street=&geo_col_postcode=&geo_col_town=&geo_col_country=AT&col_note=
```

notice /offerselect is removed from url.

This can be seen from the response headers, hopefully this helps you,

Request URL:

```
https://www.sixt.ie/php/reservation?tab_identifier=1526583730&uci=1385&rci=1385&uli=IE&rli=IE&layout=list&posl=IE&is_corpcust=&has_social_login=&pu_eq_ret=1&uda=25.05.2018&uti=10%3A00&geo_del_name=&geo_del_street=&geo_del_postcode=&geo_del_town=&geo_del_country=AT&del_note=&rda=26.05.2018&rti=09%3A30&geo_col_name=&geo_col_street=&geo_col_postcode=&geo_col_town=&geo_col_country=AT&col_note=
```

Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK

Comment: Thank you ! This will do the job! Meanwhile I ended up using selenium for date picking.